# Disconnecting Sparse SVN Updates From Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I have previously written an eclipse feature that works with eclipse to

1. sparsely update directories from svn, and
2. delete directories from the working copy *without* deleting them from the repository.

In this way you can pick and chose which subsystems you wish to work with. This feature works with subclipse.

For example, the effect if executed as a command sequence would be:

```
# check out the libs folder but not its children
svn update --depth empty libs

# check out the libs I am interested in
svn update libs/lib1 libs/lib7

... <work on them> ...

# not interested in lib1 anymore
rm -rf libs/lib1

# update to let libs know that lib1 is no longer checked out
svn update libs
```

I have recently noticed that subversive is now able to handle updating from svn sparsely. My question is, aside from the command line or writing an eclipse feature as I have, is there a way to disconnect and delete a sparse update from the working copy *without* deleting from the svn repository through eclipse? Has anyone else dealt with this issue using subclipse, subversive or any other team provider?

I am currently testing with Indigo SR1.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run:

svn up --set-depth=exclude lib1

In Subclipse you can do Team > Update to Version ... and then choose Exclude in the Depth drop-down and check the box to change the WC to the selected depth.

I personally prefer using depth=empty because then the folder still exists and it is easy later to change the folder depth back to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the "update".This is exactly what I needed to know. However, how do we first checkout/update the sparse child with subclipse?

Comment: The reason that we need to do this is because we have 100-200 libraries which turns our projects view into a scrolling pain and also because our build system. Having many empty folders that could not be distinguished from non-empty folders might also be hard to use/browse/search in this case.

Comment: The Checkout dialog has a depth option.  I usually checkout with the "Immediates" option, which gives me the initial skeleton, then expand the folders I want.  Or use a script like this http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/svn-viewspec.py to checkout outside Eclipse and then just import the result into Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is what we do. However we do not use "immediates" and only selectively update what we need to prevent clutter. I did not know of the "exclude" option and this was a good tip. I wrote the feature to get around this but it is not the work of an expert. Any chance of a subclipse _include_ / exclude enhancement? That would be really cool...